# How do I patch all documents of a certain type in RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb

I've changed my data model and need to change a property of all my objects to null because deserializing them after my model changed throws an exception.

I'm guessing I could issue a patch for every document but I can't find any way to do just that, patching every document of a certain type. I need the Ids.

So I could retrieve a list of Ids for all my documents and then create a patch for every single document using those Ids. But then I'll have to retrieve the Ids without the object being deserialized, because deserialization throws an exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can patch documents based on an index, see http://ravendb.net/documentation/set-based

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is there a way to do this using the client API or will I have to do this using curl or a WebRequest?

Comment: You can do patching using the Client API. Check out the tests: https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/tree/master/Raven.Tests/Patching

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Patch command in the Studio (v3 onwards).

Go from "Documents" to "Patch" view (top left dropdown) and you can choose a collection (ie documents of a certain type) to patch. There are examples given there of javascript syntax you can use to patch the collection.